# Why do libraries like bottleneck for numpy exist?

Tags: python, performance, numpy

Sorry if this is too general of a question - just from a software engineering perspective this makes no sense.

There's a Python library called [Bottleneck](https://pypi.org/project/Bottleneck/) for Python, which serves to run certain numpy methods faster. For example, using bottleneck.nansum as opposed to np.nansum made my program run extremely faster.

My confusion comes from this - if the bottleneck methods are so much better, why doesn't numpy just do what bottleneck does? What am I missing?

Comment: Different people created each one. Maybe the authors of numpy don't trust/haven't finished going through the review process needed to adopt the Bottleneck way of doing things. Maybe their pride gets in the way. Maybe the Bottleneck author politely asked the Numpy authors not to adopt it.

Comment: people have no time to do everything. Maybe someday numpy will use faster method. Or maybe they need current version for some other reason. Better ask numpy's authors.

Comment: A reasonable question but probably too broad. The library does list restrictions but it very could have possibly been included into numpy instead since the dtype check is cheap. Then again, they could equally have rejected a proposal for these accelerations for any number of reasons like backwards compatibility or being too niche to want to keep maintaining along with their more-general codebase too

Comment: Without citations in `github` issues or pull requests (either side) or references in development forums, these are all guesses. We don't know if the `bottleneck` developers are interested in a merger.  Most of the `bottleneck` functions involve `nan`.  The `numpy` versions first use `_replace_nan` to replace `nan` and make a mask.  This step probably accounts for most of the slow down (cf. to `np.sum` etc).